# как получить список всех участников в 2021году?

Tags: python, discord.py

Мне нужно получить в формате списка всех участников сервера, у меня не работает `ctx.guild.members` она выводит только самого бота, а не других участников, как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего у вас выключены intents

Необходимо перейти по на сайт [discord.com/developers](https://discord.com/developers/applications)

Вкладка `applications`, выбрать приложение, перейти во вкладку `bot` и поставить 2 первые галочки под `Privileged Gateway Intents`

Comment: не работает((((

Comment: Исправьте ваше обращение, приписав код(```ваш код```)